# Create a n number of list to group 50 number in each untill n number reached

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to create list for each 50 numbers. Could any one suggest best way to do that.

example

I have number from 1 to 112
I want [[1..50],[51..100],[101..112]]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a while loop:

```
n = 112
i = 1
res = []
while i <= n:
    res.append(list(range(i, min(i+50, n+1))))
    i += 50
```

`res` will then be:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
  [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100],
  [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]
]
```

Edit: alternatively you can use [`more_itertools.chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked):

```
from more_itertools import chunked
n = 112
list(chunked(range(1, n+1), 50))
```

Or a comprehension:

```
n = 112
r = range(1, n+1)
[list(r[i:i+50]) for i in range(0, n, 50)]
```